# Problem running xepersian with xelatex

Tags: xetex, miktex, xepersian

I have to test something with the Persian language but it already fails in the preamble.
My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{B Zar}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The error message (already ran it in administrator mode, in user mode same problem):

```
2018-06-09 14:49:13,100+0200 INFO  miktex-maketfm - starting with command line: miktex-maketfm -v OT
2018-06-09 14:49:13,101+0200 WARN  miktex-maketfm - running with administrator privileges
2018-06-09 14:49:13,117+0200 INFO  maketfm - Making OT.tfm from "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\public\othello\OT.mf"...
2018-06-09 14:49:13,124+0200 INFO  maketfm - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2018-06-09 14:49:13,125+0200 INFO  maketfm - running: miktex-mf.exe --undump=mf \mode:=ljfour; nonstopmode; "input OT"
2018-06-09 14:49:14,550+0200 INFO  maketfm - METAFONT failed for some reason
2018-06-09 14:49:14,553+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - No such file or directory: path="OT.log"
2018-06-09 14:49:14,554+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: path="OT.log"
2018-06-09 14:49:14,554+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2018-06-09 14:49:14,554+0200 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 561
```

Comment: You seem not to have the font, use another one. And don't load inputenc with xelatex.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any idea how I can obtain the font or an alternative font (I get similar messages with XB Niloofar).

Comment: I found some fonts on my machine with which I can mimic my tests (it are Arabic fonts), Would be better though when I have a Persian / Farsi font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, you shouldn't use `inputenc` alongside XePersian package.

**Second**, it seems that you don't have the font on your system. You can get some free Persian fonts [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/search?lang=Farsi), like this [one](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/yas), or you can just simply use a common font such as *Arial*.